# How to invert (invert_yaxis()) when there using set_yticklabels

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use .invert_yaxis(), but there will be error message when using set_yticklabels.
Is it there is anyway to use invert on code below?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 5.7]
y = np.arange(len(x))
fsize=(2,2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=fsize)

ax.set_yticklabels(list(' abcd')) #if the abcd is data which get from upper code

ax.barh(y,x,align='center',color='grey')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `set_yticklabels` it is strongly recommended to first set `set_yticks`. In general, matplotlib decides internally where to put the ticks. Small changes in the code could put the ticks on different positions. By explicitly using `set_yticks` you can be sure about their positions.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 5.7]
y = np.arange(len(x))
fsize=(2,2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=fsize)

ax.barh(y,x,align='center',color='grey')
ax.set_yticks(y)
ax.set_yticklabels(list('abcd')) #if the abcd is data which get from upper code
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]